# (R, dplyr) select multiple columns starts with same string and summarise mean (90% CI) by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to tidyverse, conceptually I would like to calculate mean and 90% CI of all columns starts with "ab", grouped by "case". Tried many ways but none seem to work, my actual data has many columns so explicitly list them out is not an option.

#### test data below

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(case= c("case1", "case1", "case2", "case2", "case3"), 
              abc = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2), 
              abe = c(1, 3, 2, 3, 4), 
              bca = c(1, 6, 3, 8, 9))
```

#### below code is what i would like to do conceptually, but doesn't work, obviously

```
dat %>% group_by(`case`) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(select(starts_with("ab"))), 
            qt=quantile(select(starts_with("ab"), prob=c(0.05, 0.95))))
```

#### what I would like to get is something like below

```
case abc_mean abe_mean abc_lb abc_ub abe_lb abe_ub

  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 case1      1.5      2.0   1.05   1.95   1.10   2.90
2 case2      2.0      2.5   1.10   2.90   2.05   2.95
3 case3      2.0      4.0   2.00   2.00   4.00   4.00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, just move that `select` before the `summarise`. We then use `summarise_all`, and specify the appropriate functions within `funs`.

```
dat %>%
    group_by(case) %>%
    select(starts_with('ab')) %>%
    summarise_all(funs('mean' = mean, 'ub' = quantile(., .95), 'lb' = quantile(., .05)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#    case abc_mean abe_mean abc_ub abe_ub abc_lb abe_lb
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 case1      1.5      2.0   1.95   2.90   1.05   1.10
# 2 case2      2.0      2.5   2.90   2.95   1.10   2.05
# 3 case3      2.0      4.0   2.00   4.00   2.00   4.00
```

We use `summarise_all` instead of `summarise` because we wish to perform the same operations on *multiple* columns. It requires far less typing to use `summarise_all` instead of a `summarise` call in which we specify each column and each operation separately.

Comment: Could you clarify why we use summarise_all as opposed to summarise? I have read the documentation on the functions and don't understand the difference.

Comment: I have added a brief explanation, I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: solved. thanks! what I missed in attempts before is the funs() part:)

Comment: I am glad you were able to find a solution. Consider following @ycw's advice and accept either my solution or their solution, so that others know this question has a solution. :)

Comment: just accepted urs, my first question here actually, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Another option is `summarise_at`. `vars(starts_with("ab"))` is for selecting columns, `funs(...)` is to apply summarzing functions.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(case) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("ab")), funs(mean = mean(.),
                                             lb = quantile(., prob = 0.05),
                                             ub = quantile(., prob = 0.95))) 
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#    case abc_mean abe_mean abc_lb abe_lb abc_ub abe_ub
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 case1      1.5      2.0   1.05   1.10   1.95   2.90
# 2 case2      2.0      2.5   1.10   2.05   2.90   2.95
# 3 case3      2.0      4.0   2.00   4.00   2.00   4.00
```

#### Update

An updated option with the `across` function.

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(case) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("ab"), .fns = list(
    mean = ~mean(.x),
    lb = ~quantile(.x, prob = 0.05),
    ub = ~quantile(.x, prob = 0.95))
  ))

dat2
# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#   case  abc_mean abe_mean abc_lb abe_lb abc_ub abe_ub
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 case1      1.5      2     1.05   1.1    1.95   2.9 
# 2 case2      2        2.5   1.1    2.05   2.9    2.95
# 3 case3      2        4     2      4      2      4
```

Comment: @Lab.J I am glad it helps. If possible, please accept either mine or bouncyball's answer based on your preference to let others know this question has a solution.

Comment: for more info on how to accept the answer see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346447)