# (R, dplyr) Put summarise_all data into a data frame of its own

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Unfortunately I don't have enough points to make a comment, but I have a lingering question about the help in this post: [(R, dplyr) select multiple columns starts with same string and summarise mean (90% CI) by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293652/r-dplyr-select-multiple-columns-starts-with-same-string-and-summarise-mean-9/47293761#47293761)

Here's the working code from that post:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(case) %>%
    select(starts_with('ab')) %>%
    summarise_all(funs('mean' = mean, 'ub' = quantile(., .95), 'lb' = quantile(., .05)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#    case abc_mean abe_mean abc_ub abe_ub abc_lb abe_lb
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 case1      1.5      2.0   1.95   2.90   1.05   1.10
# 2 case2      2.0      2.5   2.90   2.95   1.10   2.05
# 3 case3      2.0      4.0   2.00   4.00   2.00   4.00
```

Can I direct this output into a dataframe of its own? I'm having two issues, first, it's not printing all of my data instead it prints:

```
    # A tibble: 2 x 13
  STATION TMPMX1_mean TMPMX2_mean TMPMX3_mean TMPMX4_mean TMPMX5_mean TMPMX6_mean TMPMX7_mean
  <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 300220        -1.45       -0.13        5.45        12.8        19.3        24.0        26.2
2 303025        -1.77       -0.53        4.92        12.0        18.6        23.2        25.5
# ... with 5 more variables: TMPMX8_mean <dbl>, TMPMX9_mean <dbl>, TMPMX10_mean <dbl>,
#   TMPMX11_mean <dbl>, TMPMX12_mean <dbl>
```

When I try to put this data into a dataframe, using the previous example it would look like this:

```
df<-dat %>%
group_by(case) %>%
select(starts_with('ab')) %>%
summarise_all(funs('mean' = mean))
```

But I get a "group_by" error saying "Adding missing grouping variables: 'case'"

So my questions are (1) how do I get summarise_all to show all data and (2) how do I route this data directly into a data frame.

Thank you!

Comment: at the end of code add `%>% as.data.frame()`, `tibble` format hides the data on console.

Comment: `Adding missing groups` is a *warning* not an *error*, and you will always see it unless/until you include the grouping variables in the `select`ion. Specifically, it is not letting you forget to include the grouping variables (since the grouping is moot without it). In this case, change it to `select(case, starts_with("ab"))` and the warning goes away.

Comment: Further, when you say *"instead it prints"*, it sounds like you don't understand what's going on here. In R (as with many languages), there is a difference between what an object *is* and how it is *displayed*. For instance, `pi` will likely give you just 6 decimal places, but understand that there are many more stored. With `tibble`s, it tries to make things aesthetically "easy" to see the gist of as much of the frame as possible, but it strongly avoids line-wrap and confusing clutter. I often use `str(df)` to see it from a different perspective (also `glimpse`).

Comment: Lastly, doing `df <- dat %>% ...` is fine, the summary should now be stored in the variable named `df`. Note that there is also a function named `df`, which you are somewhat masking here. Generally not a problem unless/until (a) you want to access the F-distribution; or (b) you try to access the *data* `df` but forgot to define it, in which case you'll get a potentially really-confusing error about `invalid 'type' (closure)` ... once you know that "closure" is CS-speak for "a function and its environment", you might recall this comment and see one pitfall of using a variable name of `df`.

Comment: Thank you @YOLO and @r2evans! This is all really helpful